# Powershell Regex to match IP and two wildcards

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm writing a small utility which requires user input of either IP address or hostname. I'd like to validate the IP address, which could contain the PS wildcards of '*' or '?'

I've got this Regex so far, which will match a valid IP address and the '*' wildcard:

```
[regex]$IPmatch = "^((([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\*)\.){3}(([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])|\*)$"
```

I'm now a bit stuck as to how to add in the '?' wildcard, which can be subsituted for any single digit e.g.

True:

```
('192.1??.2?.1' -match $IPmatch)
('19?,?68,*.*' -match $IPMatch)
```

Edit:

This seems to work?

```
[regex]$IPmatch = "^((([0-9\?]{1,2})|([1\?][0-9\?]{2,2})|([2\?][0-4\?][0-9\?])|(25[0-5\?])|\*)\.){3}(([0-9\?]{1,2})|([1\?][0-9\?]{2,2})|([2/?][0-4\?][0-9\?])|(25[0-5\?])|\*)$"
```

Comment: Just add `?` to the digit character classes

Comment: Tried it - see above - this seems to work, can anyone see any issues?

Comment: Just for the record, you might wanna take a look at [System.Net.IPAddress] too. Compare `[System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("192.168.1.256")` and `[System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("192.168.1.1")` for instance. I missed the part about the wildcards.

Comment: Yes, I was half hoping there'd be a class method seeing as PS allows these wildcards but I couldn't find one

Comment: ? => does this mean exactly one Digit or 0-1 Digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback - this code below seems to have the desired effect of validating an IP address plus allowing asterisk as full wildcard with question mark as placeholder for single digit - I've used a backtick halfway through to make it more readable here

```
[regex]$IPmatch = "^((([0-9\?]{1,2})|([1\?][0-9\?]{2,2})|([2\?][0-4\?][0-9\?])|(25[0-5\?])|\*)\.)`
{3}(([0-9\?]{1,2})|([1\?][0-9\?]{2,2})|([2\?][0-4\?][0-9\?])|(25[0-5\?])|\*)$"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to just replace the wildcards with a valid number (1):

```
PS> $ipObject = $null
PS> $ip = "192.1??.2?.1" -replace "[?*]","1"
PS> [System.Net.IPAddress]::TryParse($ip, [ref]$ipObject)
True

PS> $ip = "192.1??.*.*" -replace "[?*]","1"
PS> [System.Net.IPAddress]::TryParse($ip, [ref]$ipObject)
True
```

Comment: Why would I want that? I just want to validate the string, which will then be used to search for all matches in an object property. This way I'd have to validate twice?

Comment: @Scepticalist: It's a way to avoid the mind-bending regex; more concisely: `[bool] (('192.1??.*.*' -replace '[?*]', '1') -as [Net.IPAddress])` That said, `[System.Net.IPAddress]` doesn't provide the desired validation, because it also happily parses strings such as `'1'` or `'10.1'`

Comment: Point taken. For my purposes I think I'll use the regex string as it ensures a full IP address is input - but I can see the use of this way too.

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo in the last octet. `/` instead of `\`, so that this would be considered as valid:
`('111.168.1./49' -match $IPMatch)`

Other than that, this is working as you would expect. It is hard to dig through though. mhu's answer seems much more readable.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll put it in as an answer